# Database getting closed by itself

Tags: java, android, sqlite

This happened for the first time, as soon as I am done with executing queries database connection gets closed. In following code, just after the first loop when I try to execute more queries I am getting an error that database connection is already closed. If I manually open database again then the code runs fine i.e. queries execute without any error.

Why is the database getting closed when I am not doing it?

openDB() and closeDB() are opening and closing connection to database.

Code: http://pastie.org/5587804#32,34

```
public void insertCheckedValuesInTable(int test_id,
            ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> checkedValues) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        openDB();
        // first collect all the values then insert
        // insert test_id, Q_id , correct answer and submitted answer in table
        // testAnswerSubmitted

        for (int i = 0; i < checkedValues.size(); i++) {
            int Q_id = getQ_id(checkedValues.get(i).get(0).toString().trim());
            String correctAns = getCorrectAnswer(
                    test_id,
                    Integer.parseInt(checkedValues.get(i).get(0).toString()
                            .trim()));
            String submittedAns = checkedValues.get(i).get(1).toString().trim();
            int marksObt;
            Log.e("value " + i, correctAns.equalsIgnoreCase(submittedAns) + "");
            // get marks
            if (correctAns.equalsIgnoreCase(submittedAns)) {
                // = marks for this question;
                Cursor cur = myDataBase.rawQuery(
                        "(SELECT Marks FROM testQuestionBank WHERE Test_id ="
                                + test_id + " AND Q_id = " + Q_id + ")", null);
                cur.moveToFirst();
                marksObt = Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(0));
                cur.close();
            } else {
                marksObt = 0;
            }
            // done collecting all values, insert in db now

            Log.e("database state", myDataBase.isOpen() + "");

            openDB();

            String sql = "Insert INTO testAnswerSubmitted (Test_id, Q_id, CorrectAnswer, SubmittedAnswer, MarksObtained) VALUES ( "
                    + test_id
                    + ", '"
                    + Q_id
                    + "', '"
                    + correctAns
                    + "', '"
                    + submittedAns + "', '" + marksObt + "') ";
            myDataBase.execSQL(sql);
            Log.v("Executed", sql);
        }
        closeDB();
    }
```

openDB():

```
public void openDB() {
        try {
            createDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("DataBaseHelper", e.toString());
        }

        openDataBase();
        getWritableDatabase();

    }
```

where createDatabase() is :

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {

            // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            // this.getReadableDatabase(); // changed to write
            this.getWritableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }
```

closeDB():

```
@Override
    public synchronized void close() {

        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();

    }
```

Comment: It would be better if you post code here only rather than giving link to somewhere else, because it helps future visitor also in that case this link may become outdated.

Comment: Why do you open the database twice? Just curious.

Comment: What is in the open/close methods? The second open method might close the database for all we know?

Comment: @PradeepSimha I cant highlight the lines of interest here thats why didn't paste here. Edited though.

Comment: Can you please let us know code in closeDB() and openDB()?

Comment: @Ewald This is why I am asking this, db is getting closed there so I opened it again and it works fine, but why?

Comment: @AyushGoyal I see - interesting - can it be the cursor that forces a close? Or does your database close as soon as there's no more connections to it?

Comment: @PradeepSimha added more code as asked..

Comment: Also small doubt why are you opening db twice?

Comment: I think somewhere you are calling close() in getWritableDatabase();??

Comment: @PradeepSimha Just above the second openDB() in Log I am getting the state closed, thats why I added another openDB() to just make the code work. I want to know why database state is closed at this point

Comment: @AyushGoyal cur.close(); this line maybe problem, try commenting it and running again

Comment: Any luck when not closing the cursor like @PradeepSimha suggested?

Comment: I can not find the piece of code where you actually open the connection to sqlite and pass the reference to your myDataBase variable, which you are using in your closeDB() method and your Log.e line of code. Also, your openDB() method is not trivial as a lot of stuff is happening there. Therefore, to find the issue I would move your Log.e line of code around and try to find the location where you actually lose your connection to the db. For example, you could check whether you have a connection after the first openDB() statement and so on.

Comment: commented out cur.close but still the state is closed